# Showing avatar for Core MVC using Azure AD Authentication (B2C)

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have a ASP.NET Core MVC application that is integrated with our Azure AD.  In the default template that is created for a new MVC project, it shows the name of the logged in user, but I'd like to show the avatar as well (image associated with the user like Azure does when logging into the portal).

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Microsoft Graph API to get the photo of the current user :

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value
```

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0

To use Microsoft Graph API , you need to get access token in your MVC application using [MSAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet) :

```
private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedContext context)
{
    var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(context.Options.ClientSecret);
    var userId = context.Principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
    var tokenCache = new SessionTokenCache(context.HttpContext, userId);

    var confidentialClientApplication = new ConfidentialClientApplication(
        context.Options.ClientId,
        context.Options.Authority,
        _options.RedirectUri,
        clientCredential,
        tokenCache.GetInstance(),
        null);

    try
    {
        var authenticationResult = await confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(context.ProtocolMessage.Code, _options.ApiScopes.Split(' '));
        context.HandleCodeRedemption(authenticationResult.AccessToken, authenticationResult.IdToken);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // TODO: Handle
        throw;
    }
}
```

please refer to code sample :

https://github.com/chrispadgettlivecom/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNetCore21/tree/master/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNetCore21

Or using the [Microsoft Graph Client Library for .NET (SDK)](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet)

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-connect-sample